# how to have two lines on one chart in Ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Below is the sample data. My primary question is whether or not using Ggplot, I can graph lines for the two industries (11 and 22) without having to use pivot_wider? I am looking for a line chart that shows the employment for both industries. I can do a pivot wider but hoping to avoid this in this case.

```
periodyear <- c(2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
period <- c(01,02,03,04,05,06,01,02,03,04,05,06,01,02,03,04,05,06,01,02,03,04,05,06)
indcode <- c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22)
employment <- c(1540,1550,1560,1555,1570,1575,1600,1605,1595,1608,1615,1640,895,900,905,910,920,925,930,940,955,940,945,920)

twoseries <- data.frame(periodyear,period,indcode,employment)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for since there is no need to `pivot_longer` anything. The data is already in a tidy format.

```r
library(ggplot2)

twoseries %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = periodyear, y = employment, group = indcode, color = as.factor(indcode))) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Period Year", y = "Employment", color = "Industries")
```

This returns

[image]

(Simplified thanks to Gregor Thomas)

Comment: I somehow forgot about the `labs` command... *facepalming*